# google map api v2 it was appearing [Android]

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

The map was appearing then now it is just gray blank screen with zoom buttons, i changed
the api key nothing changed re-install google play service in android sdk and also nothing changed.

Any Help !!
http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8752555837_4bd5d0abee_m.jpg

Thanks

Comment: will you post your code ?

Comment: Check API key is correct and or not

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly set the API up. It is most probably related to API key.

Comment: explain please i'm an android developer beginner 
??

Comment: @NesreenMansour follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key and make sure you did this: "In the list of services displayed in the center of the page, scroll down until you see Google Maps Android API v2. To the right of the entry, click the switch indicator so that it is on."